# Google Plus connect API using jQuery/Ajax

Tags: ajax, google-plus

I am trying to trigger the Google plus connect API within a jquery/ajax function.
The response I get is undefined. Firebug shows an empty response.

This is the code I am using:

```
function gPlusConnect ()
{
    console.debug('line 401 ajax gestartet');
    result=$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,   // false
        url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth', 
        data: ({
            scope:'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
            state:'/profile',
            redirect_uri:'https://ssl.webpack.de/learnface.de/donation/launchpages',
            response_type:'code',
            client_id:'.........82.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        })
    }).responseText;
    console.debug('index.php 415 ajax ends with '+result+' from g+');
}
```

The result in firebug is:

```
Header      Post      Antwort   HTML
index.php    415        ajax    ends undefined from g+
```

Has anyone done this successfully? Do you recommend a better alernative?

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot easier to use OAuth 2.0 on Google with the official client libraries. Authorizing users this way with the JavaScript client library is really easy:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
<script>
function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
  gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
}
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  console.log(authResult);
}
</script>
```

You can find a more [detailed sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/source/browse/samples/authSample.html) in the source code tree for the client library, and learn more about the library on its [code hosting project](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/).